# Changing DOM elements by reference

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dynamic, reference

Let's say I have a paragraph of text in a HTML file. Using TreeWalker I pushed every non-empty text node to an array:

```
function getTextNodes(elem) {
    var textNodes = [];
    var nextNode;

    var treeWalker = document.createTreeWalker(elem, NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT, {
        acceptNode: function(node) {
            return node.textContent !== "\n" ? NodeFilter.FILTER_ACCEPT : NodeFilter.FILTER_REJECT;
        }
    }, false);

    var counter = 1;

    while (nextNode = treeWalker.nextNode()) {
        textNodes.push(nextNode);

        console.log("Pushed " + counter + " times.");

        counter++;
    }

    return textNodes;
}
```

When I try to change the contents of the array, like replacing every element with the string "changed ", nothing happens in the browser window.

Is it somehow possible storing the nodes by reference, such that every time they are changed, the text in the browser changes, too?

EDIT:

```
function changeTextNodes(elem) {
    for (var i = 0; i < elem.length; i++) {
        elem[i] = "change ";
    }
}
```

The code that changes the array elements.

EDIT2:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    changeTextNodes(getTextNodes(document.body));
});
```

Here's how the 2 functions are called.

Comment: Where's the code that tries to change the nodes? If that's the code that's not working, then it should be posted here or else nobody can help. Also, your loop does not just post text nodes, because `.textContent` will return content from element nodes too.

Comment: @Pointy: .textContent is just used to filter out TextNodes which contain only "\n". The main filter is the parameter before that.

Comment: oh right, I see; sorry about that.

Comment: @Pointy No biggie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code that attempts to change the text examines the array result from gathering up the nodes. That array consists of **nodes**, so if you want to modify the content you need to do that through the node API. Currently, your code just modifies the array contents, which will have no effect on the DOM; it's just a JavaScript array.

To change the content, you'd modify the `nodeValue` property:

```
for (var i = 0; i < elem.length; i++) {
    elem[i].nodeValue = "change ";
}
```